# AngularJS: Get data from object under multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using Angular here:

I am creating dynamic controls and tabs based on the json I get. So if my incoming json object is like below then I am creating 2 master tabs and then child tabs under them.

```
"MasterTab1": {
  "tab1": ["somedata1-1", "somedata1-2"],
  "tab2": ["somedata2-1", "somedata2-2"]
},
"MasterTab2": {
  "tab1": ["somedata2-1-1", "somedata2-1-2"],
  "tab2": ["somedata2-2-1", "somedata2-2-2"],
  "tab3": ["somedata2-3-1", "somedata2-3-2"]
}
```

Now each child tabs can have some controls under them, like textbox, dropdowns etc example as below:

```
 <tabset class="tabbable-line">
    <tab ng-repeat="(key,value) in tabstest1" heading="{{key}}">
      <tabset class="tabbable-line">
        <tab class="tabbable-line" ng-if="key=='MasterTab1'" ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in value" heading="{{k2}}">
        {{ v2 }}
        </tab>
        <tab class="tabbable-line" ng-if="key=='MasterTab2'" ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in value" heading="{{k2}}">
        {{ v2 }}
        </tab>
      </tabset>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

I have created demo as below. The demo contains few controls that can be inside the tabs.

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/43qj5kys/1/

What I am stuck is, once user fills in the controls and the data how shall I get the data from there.

I have a button click, when the user clicks on this button I want to get all the data which the user selected in all the controls of these tabs.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Anyone?

Comment: Why are you using such an obsolete, old version of `angular-ui-bootstrap`? The [answer you accepted two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780102/5535245) used a more relevant version of the library.

Comment: @georgeawg if you see the comment I posted there I mentioned that I am using that version and I cannot upgrade that at this point. I accepted that answer as I used  that answer code to fit my case. Would you have inputs on my question above?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fg3b18t7/ ?

Comment: @AlonEitan yes thanks that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be stored in properties of `$scope.master1` and `$scope.master2`, after you defined them as objects in your controller.

```
$scope.master1 = {};
$scope.master2 = {};
```

see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/6znkufs2/

Comment: querty this does not fully work. When I change the dropdown it does update the json. But for my second row when I update that it replaces my json with the value selected. What I want is to construcct the entire json with all the values from all the tabs.